# how to add Validation stuff in my asp.net mvc3 when i use EF with database first?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have a problem with my mvc3 application, i need to create some Validation stuff. but i dont have a normal model class because i have used EF with the database first approach.

i can not just open the class and write something like:

```
[Required]
[StringLength(10)]
```

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [MetadataType attribute](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2011/01/20/adding-metadata-to-entities-in-the-data-model.aspx). So let's suppose that EF spit at your face the following class which you cannot modify:

```
public partial class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Now you could extend it since it is a [partial class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx):

```
[MetadataType(typeof(FooMetadata))]
public partial class Foo
{
}
```

and then define the metadata:

```
public class FooMetadata
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Or, simply throw data annotations away and use a real validation framework such as [FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) (which I use and strongly recommend) allowing you to express complex validation rules on your models in a fluent manner, has an [excellent integration with ASP.NET MVC](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation) and also allows you to elegantly [unit test your vaildation logic](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Testing&referringTitle=Documentation) in isolation.