# ASP.NET and EF Core - ModelState.IsValid always returns true for models generated by Scaffold-DbContext

Tags: validation, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I've been unable to validate models generated by the Scaffold-DbContext command in my ASP.NET Core controllers.

The required/max length property configurations are all in the onModelCreating method of the context class that EF core generated.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating( ModelBuilder modelBuilder ) {
    modelBuilder.Entity<ModelClass>( entity => {
        entity.ToTable( "ModelClass", "schema" );

        entity.Property( e => e.ModelClassCode )
              .IsRequired()
              .HasMaxLength( 30 );
```

My controller receives the data for the models as JSON but ModelState.IsValid always returns true even if I send invalid data.

```
public IActionResult CreateModelClass( [FromBody]ModelClass modelClass ) {
    // ModelState.IsValid always returns true here
```

The only way I've gotten ModelState.IsValid to be false is by adding data annotations to the model class. I'd like to avoid that because running the scaffold command will overwrite those changes.

Am I missing something here? Is there an example that someone can point me to? The ones I've seen related to validation are all using data annotations.

Comment: I believe the validation framework relies on the data annotations on the properties. So you need that for the modal validation to work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Shyju. I'm hoping to avoid data annotations in the model because they will get overwritten when I regenerate the models from the database.

Comment: You can use `Scaffold-DbContext` to generate data annotations instead of fluent api wherever possible. Use following command line arg
`-a|--data-annotations           Use DataAnnotation attributes to configure the model where possible. If omitted, the output code will use only the fluent API.`
That way `Required`/``MaxLength` etc will be scaffolded using annotations and will provide you validation support.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Smit. I did come across the `-DataAnnotations` switch while looking at the ASP.NET core documentation yesterday and that does work. At this point, I'm just curious why the fluent API approach doesn't seem to validate.

Comment: As @Shyju pointed out, data validation framework relies on annotations. Fluent API is EF specific thing. & EF does not provide any validation on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in @Smit's comment, you can use the `--Data-Annotations` switch in the `Scaffold-DbContext` command to generate the models with the correct validation annotations.

See the documentation for `Scaffold-DbContext` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell